# TypeErrors using metaclasses in conjunction with multiple inheritance

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, python-2.x, metaclass

I have two questions converning metaclasses and multiple inheritance. The first is: Why do I get a TypeError for the class `Derived` but not for `Derived2`?

```
class Metaclass(type): pass

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__  = Metaclass

#class Derived(object, Klass): pass # if I uncomment this, I get a TypeError

class OtherClass(object): pass

class Derived2(OtherClass, Klass): pass # I do not get a TypeError for this
```

The exact error message is:

`TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution order (MRO) for bases object, Klass`

The second question is: Why does `super` not work in this case(if I use `__init__` instead of `__new__`, `super` works again):

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, dict_):
        return super(Metaclass, self).__new__(name, bases, dict_)

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__  = Metaclass
```

There I get:

`TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases type.__new__(X):
    X is not a type object (str)`

I'm using Python 2.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second question has already been well answered twice, though `__new__` is actually a staticmethod, not a classmethod as erroneously claimed in a comment...:

```
>>> class sic(object):
...   def __new__(cls, *x): return object.__new__(cls, *x)
... 
>>> type(sic.__dict__['__new__'])
<type 'staticmethod'>
```

The first question (as somebody noted) has nothing to do with metaclasses: you simply can't multiply inherit from any two classes A and B in this order where B is a subclass of A.  E.g.:

```
>>> class cis(sic): pass
... 
>>> class oops(sic, cis): pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    Cannot create a consistent method resolution
order (MRO) for bases sic, cis
```

The MRO guarantees that leftmost bases are visited before rightmost ones - but it also guarantees that among ancestors if x is a subclass of y then x is visited before y. It's impossible to satisfy both of these guarantees in this case.  There's a good reason for these guarantees of course: without them (e.g. in old style classes, which only guarantee the left-right order in method resolution, **not** the subclass constraint) all overrides in x would be ignored in favor of the definitions in y, and that can't make much sense.  Think about it: what *does* it mean to inherit from `object` first, and from some other class second?  That `object`'s (essentially nonexistent;-) definition of its several special methods must take precedence over the other class's, causing the other class's overrides to be ignored?

Comment: makes sense, so as long I not directly inherit from object(which actually does not make sense but I wanted to be sure that nothing strange happens) it should be ok :)
I wonder if it's save to use __new__ without super.

Comment: @nils, yes `__new__` is usable w/o `super` -- except in complex cases of multiple inheritance. If you're into complex multiple inheritance, `__new__`'s more prudent.

Answer (score 4):

For the first question, have a look at [the description of MRO in python](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) - specifically, the "bad Method Resolution order" section. Essentially, it's to do with the fact that python doesn't know whether to use object or Klass's methods. (It's nothing to do with the usage of metaclasses.)

For the second question, it looks like you're misunderstanding how the `__new__` function works. It doesn't take a reference to itself as the first argument - it takes a reference to the type of the class being instantiated. So your code should look like this:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dictn):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dictn)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the second question, you need to pass self to `__new__` like this:

```
class Metaclass(type):
    def __new__(self, name, bases, dict_):
        return super(Metaclass, self).__new__(self, name, bases, dict_)

class Klass(object):
    __metaclass__  = Metaclass
```

I can't recall off the top of my head why this is, but I think it's because `type.__new__` isn't a bound method and thus doesn't magically get the self argument.

Comment: `__new__` is a classmethod, don't use self there, it's confusing

Comment: Yeah, in code where I've done this I've used `cls` or somesuch but I was following what the original poster used.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do?

```
class Derived(object, Klass):
```

Klass already derives from object.

```
class Derived(Klass):
```

Is the reasonable thing here.