# Method Resolution Order Error

Tags: python, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

This is more of a question of curiosity, rather than a serious issue:

I was playing around with multiple inheritance and came accross this:

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def __init__(self): print "A.__init__() called"
...
>>> class B(object, A): pass
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Cannot create consisten method resolution
order (MRO) for bases object, A
```

I get a `TypeError`. However, when I reverse the order of the multiple inheritance:

```
>>> class B(A, object): pass
>>> b = B()
A.__init__() called
```

It works fine. I assumed that in the first instance, the inheritance of `object` before `A` creates some kind of name ambiguity. Would anyone care to explain what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`A` is inherited from `object` or subclass of `object`, it doesn't work. The MRO guarantees that leftmost bases are visited before rightmost ones - but it also guarantees that among ancestors if x is a subclass of y then x is visited before y. It's impossible to satisfy both of these guarantees in this case

**Here is a similar question**

[Python: Problem with metaclasses in conjunction multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2203947/python-problem-with-metaclasses-in-conjunction-multiple-inheritance)